# How to only make data viewable that is within a certain time period in a Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

I am using Firebase database with an apache cordova (HTML) application to create a chatroom-like project.  I am trying to change the Firebase rules so that only messages within the past 5 minutes will be appear on the app and modeling an example on their tutorial

I have created this code in my rules section but no data shows up even when the data is entered right away

[image]

My database data looks like this

[image]

What changes do i need to make to my rules code or what kind of formatting do i need to do to my data to make this function work?  Thanks.

Comment: It seems you've applied the rules at the top-level. They should be under `$messageid`. You can often troubleshoot such cases yourself, by trying a read operation in the Simulator tab of the dashboard of your Firebase app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to solve this problem that i have found is to edit what is shown in the display in your App and then manually clear the data from your Firebase every now and then.  To control what data is accessible in your application simply add if-statement controls to whatever function deals with the 'child_added" function and also create a child node of a timestamp to every parent node you push to the database.  Using the timestamp assigned to each node and comparing it to the current timestamp using Date.now() will allow you to control not showing aged-out data.